How to link GLFW in a C program on windows in a makefile
My project structure looks like this.
lib/GLFW/glfw3.h
lib/GLFW/glfw3.dll
lib/GLFW/libglfw3dll.a
main.c
main.exe
makefile

And in my makefile I have this.
gcc main.o -o main -D GLFW_DLL -I lib/GLFW -Llib/GLFW lib/GLFW/libglfw3dll.a -lgdi32

In my main.c file I include it like so.
#include <lib/GLFW/glfw3.h>

Which gives an error when I compile saying it cannot find it.

Can you please [edit] your question to show us the full project tree? Also please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, and copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log (so we can see the actual error(s) you get).

As a guess, please read What is the difference between #include  and #include "filename"?

You were right about the quotes and carets, I switched it to quotes and it compiles now.  I get an error message saying it cannot find "glfw3.dll" when I run.

DLL files have to be in the PATH, or in the same directory as the .exe file. Possibly (I don't really know) in the working directory.

@Someprogrammerdude - When I move the glfw3.dll to the root of the project folder it finds it correctly.  Is there a way I can specify that its in the lib/GLFW/ folder?  EDIT:  Ok ty.  EDIT2:  I switched to static linking and it doesn't need the dll anymore.  :)

There are 3 steps that each need specific attention:
Compiling
Use the -I flag to add the location(s) where header (.h) files can be found.
gcc -c -o main.o main.c -DGLFW_DLL -Ilib/GLFW

Linking
Use the -L flag to add the location(s) where header import libraries (.a or .dll.a) files can be found.
Use the -l flag to specify the import library file(s) (.a or .dll.a) to link against, leaving out the lib prefix and the extention (.a or .dll.a).
gcc -o main.exe main.o -Llib/GLFW -lglfw3dll -lgdi32

Note that normally the shared import library should be called libglfw3.dll.a instead of libglfw3dll.a. In that case the flag should be -lglfw3 (which will pick up libglfw3.dll.a if you're not linking statically with the -static flag in which case it would look for libglfw3.a)
Running
The .dll file(s) your program is linked against (and the .dll file(s) those .dll file(s) are linked agains, etc.) must be found at runtime.
To make sure they are found you can:

add the location(s) of the .dll file(s) to your PATH environment variable (I don't recommend this).
copy the .dll file(s) (in this case glfw3.dll) in the same folder as the .exe file. Tip: you can use copypedeps -r from the pedeps project to do this.

